# Change my Find and Replace CODE to change everything between xml marker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have code to find and replace based on text area to multiple files (loop).
I woudl like to change find to find everything between `<variables></variables>`.
Theres a lot xml files and they have random text after `<variables>`.
App work fine to search exactly what i paste in to the field and change it in all files.

Now I have winform System.Windows.Forms.TextBox to find text. I can change it to text, label or whatever to make it `const` or maybe it is a possibility to make something like if between `<variables>` and `</variables>` is `*` then find everything. I know it is more difficult.
For now this app is only to work with a marker: `<variables>`.

I have this code to find:

```
private bool FindAndReplace(string file)
{
   string content = string.Empty;
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
   {
     content = sr.ReadToEnd();
   }
   string searchText = GetSearchText(findWhatString);

   if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText))
   {
      string newText = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceWithText);
      using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
      {
         sw.Write(newText);
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

all code:
[NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZTtMz)

edit: it works but I need to write "variable" in winform to make it start searching

```
 private bool FindAndReplace(string file)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            //Read the file into the string variable.
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string searchText = GetSearchText(findWhatString);
        if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText))
        {
            string newText = Regex.Replace(content, "(?<=<variables>).+?(?=</variables>)", replaceWithText);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                sw.Write(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex for matching between `<variables></variables>`

```
 (?<=<variables>).+?(?=</variables>)
```

I don't think that you  need to deal with Regex Options. Only if you need multiline Regex.

Check [This Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C7WGD1)

Comment: I have updated 1st post, can u show me it on regex options how to do that? Truly I'm new with this regex.

Comment: I know I should not ask for it but can You show me where I need to change it?
I have edited my 1st post to paste fiddle link with all code. I'm not good in c#.

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText, GetRegExOptions()))` change this line

Comment: `string searchText = Regex.IsMatch(content, "(?<=< variables >).+? (?=</ variables >)");

            if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText))
            {` it says it cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'. If I use `Match` System.TExt.RegularRxpressions.Match to 'string'

Comment: what are you trying to do? prepare your statement in .net fiddle and send it to me

Comment: Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZTtMz Can't make it work with match and replace regex

Comment: `string searchText = GetSearchText(findWhatString);
            
            if (Regex.IsMatch(content, searchText))
            {string newText = Regex.Replace(content, "(?<=<variables>).+?(?=</variables>)", replaceWithText); ` now it works but i need to write in winforms "variables" to make it search... can u tell me how make it constant?